# Java equivalent to C# TextBox TextChanged event

Tags: c#, java, swing, jtextfield, textchanged

in C# there is an event for textboxes as follows

```
private void fooText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something 
}
```

the code in the fooText_TextChanged is fired once the text within the textbox is altered.

What is the java equivalent to this? Or how can something similar to this be achieved in java?

Thanks for any feedback/help/advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Swing, If you wanted to be notified *after* the text component's text had changed, you'd use a DocumentListener that was added to the JTextComponent's Document. e.g.,

```
  JTextField myField = new JTextField();

  myField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }

     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }

     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }
  });
```

If on the other hand, you wanted to check text *before* it has been committed to the text component, you'd add a DocumentFilter to the JTextComponent's Document.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, I'll check this out :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend registering a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to your *component's document*. Therein, you'll listen for [`DocumentEvent`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b131/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html)s.

Comment: Actually you add the DocumentListener to the Document not the component.