# How to restrict SWT text field to a set amount of characters?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, text-processing

Is there a built-in method for stopping user input when a certain number of characters have been entered?  I was looking for an alternative to VerifyListeners.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that you want the input to your text field to be limited to a certain number of characters (at the same time)? In that case, you can use [`Text.setTextLimit()`](https://help.eclipse.org/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html&anchor=setTextLimit(int)) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25892975/)).

Answer (score -1):

Sure there is. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136794/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-jtextfield) answers or perhaps [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LimitJTextFieldinputtoamaximumlength.htm) that is not attaching an event handler (or at least, not directly) for key pressed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: don't understand mate, please explain more. Thanks. If you know please collaborate.

Comment: @Basilevs, i will delete this, please remove your donwvote! (there was no need at all..) i guess SWT was SWING!!

Comment: If fact @Basilevs , besides downvoting why you don't try to help the original poster and do some contribution to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Reputation changes from bounties and votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained). [How does deleting work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) I'd like to know answer myself.

Comment: Okey, anyway i would like to leave this until someone really help the OP goals. Thanks.

Comment: The time has come to remove this answer then. OP got the right answer