# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text character limit

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text
I am doing

```
Text description = new Text(container, SWT.SINGLE);
description.setEditable(false);
description.setText("long string");
```

About half of the text shows up in the wizard that I am creating. I see there is a static int called LIMIT in the API. I have not been able to find where it states there is a preset on the number of characters that the Text can hold. I want to expand this to the number of characters that I need.

Comment: maybe 2,147,483,647 is the character limit?

Comment: `LIMIT` is 0x7FFFFFFF except on very old versions of Windows when it is 0x7FFF.

Comment: So I am using the setText method. The text is ~100 characters long. So the text is NOT being cutoff because of the Text object?

Comment: I just got 200 characters in a Text control (Mac OS X). Note that the control will not resize to show long text.

Comment: So the Text box is not large enough to display all of the text. When I make it editable and enabled, I am see that the text is showing up. I just need to make the text box larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text.LIMIT (2,147,483,647 or 2^31) is the maximum number of characters that can be entered into a text widget. This value can change for each version of eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

As the [API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html) mentiones, *Text.LIMIT* is a hard limit of the underlying native widget implementation. You can set the limit to another value using *Text.setTextLimit()*, but not larger than *Text.LIMIT*.

Maybe your text is not showing up, because you are using the single-line version of Text. Try instead

```
Text description = new Text(container, SWT.MULTI);
```

If it's also not working, try another [widget](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) without this limitation (e.g. StyledText).

Comment: I would say that would not work indeed when using the multi-line text with the `SWT.MULTI` style bit. Looking at the source code, the limit is only applied when the `SWT.SINGLE` bit is set (org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.105.3.v20170228-0512.jar).