# JTextField scrollable with no JScrollBar

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, scrollable, jscrollbar

Is it possible to have `JTextField` scrollable without use of `JScrollBar`.
For example, I would define field as max size `120`, but only `40` to be visible, the
rest is scrollable (left/right).
Similar, that `HTML INPUT TEXT` works.

Comment: The plain JTextField works like this

Comment: But it can be scrolled forever ?
new JTextField(40) will show 40 chars while the others will be scrolled. But I would like to limit them to stop scrolling after 
120th is filled.

Comment: Then you need to [limit the length of the JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136794/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-jtextfield)

Comment: Thats what I'm asking here. There is no such method, except setColumns
which is the same as calling the constructor with size.

Comment: Did you open the link in the previous comment? There is the answer.

Comment: Yes, but still missing (see below comment) lack of basic functionality  :)
So I wrote own class :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the user to entering 120 characters into the text field then you would use a `DocumentFilter`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a working example.

Comment: I would use this in conjunction with a `DocumentListener` (same tutorial) to alert the user when the max number of characters has been reached. For example, you can make a warning `JLabel` visible when the number of characters has reached the max, and make it invisible when it is less.

Comment: Could do this with action listener as well I guess. I don't know why such generic methods are not expanded in functionality with higher Java versions, as this is a very common need when making GUI's.