# How to limit what characters you can use in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, numbers, restrict

I'm making a calculator app and i want it so that you can only type numbers into the JTextField

```
JTextField first = new JTextField(4);
f.add(first);
```

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136794/limiting-the-number-of-characters-in-a-jtextfield

Comment: Kumaresan that's not what i meant