# How get percentage result in java swing calculator

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calculator, percentage

This code for a basic calculator
I have 2 problems:

1. How to get correct result for percentage calculation?
2. And set limit for text field?

I need text field to only read 16 digits maximum.

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;

    public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4055065492318058414L;

    private JPanel northPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;

    private JTextField field;

    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;
    private JButton b5;
    private JButton b6;
    private JButton b7;
    private JButton b8;
    private JButton b9;
    private JButton b0;

    private JButton bPlus;
    private JButton bMine;
    private JButton bMultiple;
    private JButton bDivision;
    private JButton bEqual;
    private JButton bClear;
    private JButton bErase;
    private JButton bPercent;
    private JButton bPlusMine;
    private JButton bDot;

    private double fNum;
    private double sNum;
    private double result;
    private String operation;

    private static final Font fontButton = new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Calculator().setVisible(true);

    }

    public Calculator() {

        super("Calculator");

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

            setSize(225, 300);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            setGUI();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void setGUI() {

        northPanel = new JPanel();
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        field = new JTextField(10);
        field.setEnabled(false);
        field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        field.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 32));

        northPanel.add(field);

        bErase = new JButton("<");
        bErase.setFont(fontButton);

        bPlus = new JButton("+");
        bPlus.setFont(fontButton);

        bPercent = new JButton("%");
        bPercent.setFont(fontButton);

        bMine = new JButton("-");
        bMine.setFont(fontButton);

        bMultiple = new JButton("\u00D7");
        bMultiple.setFont(fontButton);

        bDivision = new JButton("\u00F7");
        bDivision.setFont(fontButton);

        bEqual = new JButton("=");
        bEqual.setFont(fontButton);

        bClear = new JButton("c");
        bClear.setFont(fontButton);

        bPlusMine = new JButton("±");
        bPlusMine.setFont(fontButton);

        bDot = new JButton(".");
        bDot.setFont(fontButton);

        b1 = new JButton("1");
        b1.setFont(fontButton);

        b2 = new JButton("2");
        b2.setFont(fontButton);

        b3 = new JButton("3");
        b3.setFont(fontButton);

        b4 = new JButton("4");
        b4.setFont(fontButton);

        b5 = new JButton("5");
        b5.setFont(fontButton);

        b6 = new JButton("6");
        b6.setFont(fontButton);

        b7 = new JButton("7");
        b7.setFont(fontButton);

        b8 = new JButton("8");
        b8.setFont(fontButton);

        b9 = new JButton("9");
        b9.setFont(fontButton);

        bDot = new JButton(".");
        bDot.setFont(fontButton);

        b0 = new JButton("0");
        b0.setFont(fontButton);

        centerPanel.add(bErase);
        centerPanel.add(bClear);
        centerPanel.add(bPercent);
        centerPanel.add(bDivision);

        centerPanel.add(b1);
        centerPanel.add(b2);
        centerPanel.add(b3);
        centerPanel.add(bMultiple);

        centerPanel.add(b4);
        centerPanel.add(b5);
        centerPanel.add(b6);
        centerPanel.add(bMine);

        centerPanel.add(b7);
        centerPanel.add(b8);
        centerPanel.add(b9);
        centerPanel.add(bPlus);

        centerPanel.add(bPlusMine);
        centerPanel.add(b0);
        centerPanel.add(bDot);
        centerPanel.add(bEqual);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        b7.addActionListener(this);
        b8.addActionListener(this);
        b9.addActionListener(this);
        b0.addActionListener(this);
        bDot.addActionListener(this);

        bClear.addActionListener(this);
        bErase.addActionListener(this);

        bPlus.addActionListener(this);
        bMine.addActionListener(this);
        bMultiple.addActionListener(this);
        bDivision.addActionListener(this);

        bPlusMine.addActionListener(this);
        bPercent.addActionListener(this);
        bEqual.addActionListener(this);

        field.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent event) {

                if (field.getText().length() >= 10)
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 25));

                if (field.getText().length() >= 13)
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20));

                if (field.getText().length() >= 15)
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 19));

            }
        });


    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource().equals(b1))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "1");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b2))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "2");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b3))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "3");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b4))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "4");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b5))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "5");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b6))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "6");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b7))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "7");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b8))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "8");

        if (event.getSource().equals(b9))
            field.setText(field.getText() + "9");

        if (event.getSource().equals(bDot)) {

            if (field.getText().indexOf(".") == -1 && !field.getText().isEmpty())
                field.setText(field.getText() + ".");

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(b0)) {

            /*
             * if (field.getText().isEmpty()) field.setText("");
             * 
             * else
             */
            field.setText(field.getText() + "0");

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bClear)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = 0;
                sNum = 0;
                operation = null;
                field.setText(null);

            }

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bErase)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty())
                field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, field.getText().length() - 1));

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bPlus)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = "+";

            }

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bMine)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = "-";
            }
        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bMultiple)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = "\u00D7";
            }
        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bDivision)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = "\u00F7";

            }

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bEqual)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty() && operation != null) {

                sNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());

                if (operation.equals("+"))
                    result = fNum + sNum;

                else if (operation.equals("-"))
                    result = fNum - sNum;

                else if (operation.equals("x"))
                    result = fNum * sNum;

                else if (operation.equals("\u00F7"))
                    result = fNum / sNum;

                else if (operation.equals("\u00D7"))
                    result = fNum * sNum;



                field.setText(String.valueOf(result));

            }

        }

        if (event.getSource().equals(bPlusMine)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                double num = Double.valueOf(field.getText());

                if (num > 0)
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(num - (num * 2)));

                else
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(num)));

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

For text field limit, I wrote this code in `actionPerformed` method

```
if (event.getSource().equals(bPlusMine)) {

    if (field.getText().length() > 16)
        field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, 16));
}
```

But the above code does not work and I can't use keyListener because textfield is disabled and can only get value from buttons

Comment: to set a limit of 16 characters: `field.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(16));`

Comment: *"I have 2 problems:"* This is a Q&A site, not a help desk. Which is your one question for this thread? Given @c0der has already given an answer (albeit as a comment) to one, I suggest you focus on that one here, and break the other off into another question thread.

Comment: main problem is percentage result

Comment: 1) *"main problem is percentage result"* [Edit] the question to reflect that! 2) Tip: Add @c0der (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 1):

See the following code for a simple solution for calculating percent. It is meant for the output a result for the following sequence : 
Enter a number followed by division operation
Enter a second number followed by percentage operation
If that is not the flow you have in mind (it was not explained in the post), you'll need to change the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel northPanel, centerPanel;

    private JTextField field;

    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0;

    private JButton bPlus,  bMine, bMultiple, bDivision, bEqual;
    private JButton bClear, bErase, bPercent, bPlusMine, bDot;

    private double fNum, sNum, result;
    private String operation;

    private static final Font fontButton = new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20);
    private static final NumberFormat percentageFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Calculator().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Calculator() {

        super("Calculator");

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            percentageFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            setSize(225, 300);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            setGUI();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setGUI() {

        northPanel = new JPanel();
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        field = new JTextField(10);
        //limit text field to 16 characters
        field.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(16));
        field.setEnabled(false);
        field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        field.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 32));

        northPanel.add(field);

        //a repeated code is an opportunity for a method
        //the method also adds buttons to JPanel
        bErase = makeButton("<");
        bClear = makeButton("c");
        bPercent = makeButton("%");
        bDivision = makeButton("\u00F7");

        b1 = makeButton("1");
        b2 = makeButton("2");
        b3 = makeButton("3");
        bMultiple = makeButton("\u00D7");

        b4 = makeButton("4");
        b5 = makeButton("5");
        b6 = makeButton("6");
        bMine = makeButton("-");

        b7 = makeButton("7");
        b8 = makeButton("8");
        b9 = makeButton("9");
        bPlus = makeButton("+");

        bPlusMine = makeButton("±");
        b0 = makeButton("0");
        bDot = makeButton(".");
        bEqual = makeButton("=");

        field.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

            @Override
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent event) {

                //use if - else for more efficient code

                if (field.getText().length() >= 15) {
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 19));
                }
                else if (field.getText().length() >= 13) {
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20));
                }

                else if (field.getText().length() >= 10) {
                    field.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 25));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        //only one if is executed each time, so use if - else
        //or switch

        //get the text from clicked button
        String text = ((JButton)event.getSource()).getText();
        if(isInteger(text)) {
            field.setText(field.getText() + Integer.parseInt(text));
        }

        else if (text.equals(".")) {

            if ((field.getText().indexOf(".") == -1) && !field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                field.setText(field.getText() + ".");
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("c")) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = 0;
                sNum = 0;
                operation = null;
                field.setText(null);
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("<")) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {
                field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, field.getText().length() - 1));
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("+")) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = text;
            }

        }

        else if (text.equals("-")) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = text;
            }
        }


        else if (text.equals("\u00D7")) { //multiply

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = text;
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("\u00F7")) {//divide

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                fNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(null);
                operation = text;
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("%")) {

            if (("\u00F7").equals(operation)) { //% applies only after divide

                sNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());
                field.setText(String.valueOf(percentageFormat.format(fNum/sNum)));
                operation = null;
            }
        }

        else if (text.equals("=")) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty() && (operation != null)) {

                sNum = Double.valueOf(field.getText());

                if (operation.equals("+")) {
                    result = fNum + sNum;
                } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
                    result = fNum - sNum;
                } else if (operation.equals("x")) {
                    result = fNum * sNum;
                } else if (operation.equals("\u00F7")) {
                    result = fNum / sNum;
                } else if (operation.equals("\u00D7")) {
                    result = fNum * sNum;
                }

                field.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            }
        }

        else if (event.getSource().equals(bPlusMine)) {

            if (!field.getText().isEmpty()) {

                double num = Double.valueOf(field.getText());

                if (num > 0) {
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(num - (num * 2)));
                } else {
                    field.setText(String.valueOf(Math.abs(num)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isInteger(String text) {

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(text);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private JButton makeButton(String text) {

        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.setFont(fontButton);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        centerPanel.add(button);

        return button;
    }
}

//source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136854/3992939
class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {
    private int limit;
    JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
        super();
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }

        if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend to improve the code implementing to following changes:

```
//Constants  (better use enum)
    private final static String BACK ="<", CLEAR="c", DIVIDE = "\u00F7", MULTIPLY = "\u00D7",
                MINUS = "-", PLUS = "+", PLUS_MINUS = "±" , DOT = ".", EQUAL = "=" ;
    //buttons text in the same order as appear on calculator
    private final String[] buttonText = {
        BACK,CLEAR,"%",DIVIDE,"1","2","3",MULTIPLY,"4","5","6",MINUS,"7","8"
        ,"9",PLUS,PLUS_MINUS,"0",DOT,EQUAL
    };
    /* remove redundant code
    private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b0;
    private JButton bPlus,  bMine, bMultiple, bDivision, bEqual;
    private JButton bClear, bErase, bPercent, bPlusMine, bDot;
    */
```

Add a method to make all buttons:

```
private void makeButtons() {

        for(String text : buttonText) {
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            button.setFont(fontButton);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            centerPanel.add(button);
        }
}
```

And modify `setGUI()`

```
        makeButtons(); //replaces all the following code 

        /*remove redundant code 
         //a repeated code is an opportunity for a method
        //the method also adds buttons to JPanel
        bErase = makeButton("<");
        bClear = makeButton("c");
        bPercent = makeButton("%");
        bDivision = makeButton("\u00F7");

        b1 = makeButton("1");
        b2 = makeButton("2");
        b3 = makeButton("3");
        bMultiple = makeButton("\u00D7");

        b4 = makeButton("4");
        b5 = makeButton("5");
        b6 = makeButton("6");
        bMine = makeButton("-");

        b7 = makeButton("7");
        b8 = makeButton("8");
        b9 = makeButton("9");
        bPlus = makeButton("+");

        bPlusMine = makeButton("±");
        b0 = makeButton("0");
        bDot = makeButton(".");
        bEqual = makeButton("=");

         */
```

Here is a [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/aguDdTxrf8) to amended code.